# How can I hold the menu open in the JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have create a custom JComboBox, so if I try to open my comboBox, I can see the check Button near the description. This is ok. But if I want to select n items I must, open the select list, then check one items, re-open the select list, select another items, open the select list etc...
I want to open the select list one times then select the list that I want than close the select list. It is possibile to do it?

This is the CheckComboStore

```
public class CheckComboStore
{
    String id;
    Boolean state;
    String nomeArticolo;

    public CheckComboStore(String id, String nomeArticolo,Boolean state)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.nomeArticolo=nomeArticolo;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getNomeArticolo() {
        return nomeArticolo;
    }

    public void setNomeArticolo(String nomeArticolo) {
        this.nomeArticolo = nomeArticolo;
    }        
}
```

This is the code to create a comboBox with check button

```
   List<Articoli> listaArticoli = modelManager.getArticoliManager().estraiArticoli(false,false,false,false,false);
        CheckComboStore[] stores = new CheckComboStore[listaArticoli.size()];
        int i=0;
        for(Iterator<Articoli>it=listaArticoli.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
            Articoli art = it.next();
            stores[i] = new CheckComboStore(art.getCodArticoloString(),art.getNomeArticolo(),false);
            i++;
        }
    comboBoxArticoli = new ComboFormat(stores);
    comboBoxArticoli.setRenderer(new CheckComboRenderer());
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking...do you want to be able to select more than one item in the JComboBox? Would a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try adding a listener as shown below and when an item is selected you can use [`invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) and keep the popup open. It may not be the exact solution but will give you an idea. Let me know if it works for you?

```
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

      @Override
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          if (e.getItem() == combo.getItemAt(0)) //some condition {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                combo.setSelectedItem(lastSelectedItem);
                combo.showPopup();
              }
            });
          } else {
            lastSelectedItem = combo.getSelectedItem();
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but not works. If I try to attacht this, comboBoxArticoli is null, I'm try to put comboBoxArticoli instead of combo in you code, but I have null value from comboBoxArticoli.getSelectedItem()

Comment: If you are getting null in `getSelectedItem()` then it means no item is selected. Can you please verify the selected index for the combo?

Comment: I think the problem is the debugger because, if I delete SwingUtilities.invokeLater... the code are not null. Then I have change this code, I have removed the condition and put only combo.showPopup and now works.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`ItemListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemListener.html) to your combo and override `itemStateChanged` to call [`showPopup()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#showPopup()) (but don't call it on the Event Dispatch Thread, use [`SwingUtilities.InvokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable))).